# ¿Qué significa este error y cómo repararlo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

Ok amigos tengo SQL server 2008 r2 creo he habilitado el envio de Emails desde el procedure ejecutando la siguiente consulta:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

La cual me dio como resultado:

**Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'Database Mail XPs' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.**

con su palomilla de Bien ✔
 intento exec este prosedure pero no sale

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Shaiya',  
    @recipients = 'virise_001@hotmail.com',  
    @body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',  
    @subject = 'Automated Success Message' ;
```

me arroja el siguiente error:

**Msg 14607, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sysmail_verify_profile_sp, Line 42
profile name is not valid**

¿Cómo se soluciona este error?¿Sera mi SQL server es obsoleto y me falta esa funcion?¿Si alguien la tiene donde la descargo o cual debo buscar en internet o algun link por favor?

[image: CReo a este SQL Server le faltan funciones alguien me dice ¿cual descargar?]

Comment: Puedes compartir el query de tu sp ?

Comment: De donde lo saco eso no se supone ya lo tiene SQL server? ademas hay hay 2 SP cual de las dos?

Comment: Deberías asegurarte de que esta configuración sea realizada por un administrador de sistemas

Comment: Corre esta consulta y dinos que linea es la 42 
sp_helptext [sp_send_dbmail]

Comment: Obvio el administrador del sistema soy YO lo que disculpa pero no lo se todo apenas lei supe que debia activar el envio con la primera consulta pero el error no se como verlo. ¿Cual consulta no la visualizo NINGUN  EXEC de Proc?

Comment: Comentario-no-respuesta: Esa versión ya no esta soportada por MS; podrías pensar en usar una vrsión más reciente si es posible.

Comment: Alfabravo tu dices "No soportada" por que simplemente no admite el envio de correo por que perdio SOPORTE, o simplemente por que lo miras como "Viejo el SQL server"?

Answer (score 0):

Primero revisar que envie como test, luego revisar dos cosas.

1.- revisar que el profile este creado.

2.- revisar que el profile este publico.

El mensaje de error del perfil no es valido, asi que esos dos puntos te pueden ayudar.

Comment: Ok amigo solo un detalle es como verifico si esta Creado? o como lo creo?

Comment: en el management studio ingresas a la instancia, luego management o administracion y buscas database mail, click derecho, configuracion, en esa opcion puedes buscar la opcion si esta creado o crearlo en ese momento.

Comment: afff editare mi pregunta por que este es el SQL server estoy pensando que es otra version por que aqui me faltan cosas como el autoBackUps programado que es otro tema este es el que tengo y la imegen de arriba pordra observar mas detallado

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.4042.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      8.0.7601.17514
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.5420
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: dos dudas, tienes permisos de administrador? es la version sql  express?

Comment: Los detalles de cómo hacer cada uno de los pasos debería estar EN la respuesta, no en comentarios.

Comment: Revisar [answer]